# How do I split a concatenated string into multiple floating point values?

Tags: java

I'm a begginer in java I have

```
packet=090209153038020734.0090209153039020734.0
```

like this I want to split this string and store into an array like two strings:

```
1) 090209153038020734.0
2) 090209153039020734.0
```

I have done like this:

```
String packetArray[] = packets.split(packets,Constants.SF);
```

Where:
Constants.SF=0x01.

But it won't work.

Comment: its not readable... many unreadable characters in your description.

Comment: The input and output don't indicate how you want to do that... Do you want to split on a certain position, on a certain character, before or after a certain pattern, even with a more complex rule... In the state the question can't really be answered

Comment: @Bhusan, they're unreadable because they're binary protocol characters - my Firefox renders them as boxes with the hex inside (01,0f,02,03,04). @Vinze, the splitting seems obvious, it's on the 01 (STX) protocol character although I'd use substrings rather than split itself.

Answer (score 3):

I'd think twice about using split since those are obviously fixed width fields.

I've seen them before on another question here (several in fact so I'm guessing this may be homework (or a popular data collection device :-)) and it's plain that the protocol is:

- STX (0x01).
- 0x0f.
- date (YYMMDD or DDMMYY).
- time (HHMMSS).
- 0x02.
- value (XXXXXX.X).
- 0x03.
- 0x04.

And, given that they're fixed width, you should probably just use substrings to get the information out.

Answer (score 2):

The JavaDoc of String is helpful here: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

You have your String packet;

`String.indexOf(String)` gives you a position of a special substring. your interested in the  "." sign. So you write

```
int position = packet.indexOf(".")+1
```

+1 becuase you want the trailing decimal too. It will return something 20-ish and will be the last pos of the first number.

Then we use substring

`String first = packet.substring(0,position)` will give you everything up to the ".0"
`String second = packet.substring(position-1)` should give you everything starting after the ".0" and up to the end of the string.

Now if you want them explicitely into an array you can just put them there. The code as a whole - I may have some "off by one" -bugs.

```
int position = packet.indexOf(".")+1 
String first = packet.substring(0,position)
String second = packet.substring(position-1)
String[] packetArray = new String[2];
packetArray[0] = first;
packetArray[1] = second;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String packetArray[] = packets.split("\u0001");
```

should work. You are using

```
public String[] split(String regex, int limit)
```

which is doing something else: It makes sure that `split()` returns an array with at most `limit` members (1 in this case, so you get what you ask for).

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the [Javadocs for the String.split() methods](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)...you are calling the version of String.split() that takes a regular expression and a limit, but **you are passing the string itself as the first parameter**, which doesn't really make sense.

As Aaron Digulla mentioned, use the other version.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how you want to do the split. It could be based on a fixed length (number of  characters) or you want one decimal place.

If the former you could do packetArray = new String[]{packet.substring(0, 20), packet.substring(21)};

```
int dotIndex = packets.indexOf('.');
packetArray = new String[]{packet.substring(0, dotIndex+2), packet.substring(dotIndex+2)};
```

Your solution confuses the regexp with the string.

Answer (score 0):

split uses [regular expressions](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) as documented [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). Your code seems to be trying to match the whole string Constants.SF = 0x01 times, which doesn't make much sense. If you know what char the boxes are then you can use something like {[^c]+cc} where c is the character of the box (i guess this is 0x01), to match each "packet".

I think you are trying to use it like the .net String.Split(...) function?